# Regex to include special charaters on Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using notepadd++ to search and replace quite a few names.

i need to turn these

```
 Neil Kilkenny
 Mateja Kežman
 Kim Do-Heon
```

into this:

```
 Neil,Kilkenny
 Mateja,Kežman
 Kim,Do-Heon
```

So far i have got:

```
 search: ([A-Z]+)([a-z]+) ([A-Z]+)([a-z]+)
 replace: $1,$2
```

**Problem**: My regex will not match names with `ž` or `-` in them.

I thought about using `.` but i don't know how many of these special characters there are or where they will occur.

Comment: Is that all the input you have? Are there other spaces that should not be replaced?

Comment: there will never be any other spaces, i have already cleaned the file up, all that is left are the names a space and thats it.

Comment: In that case, can't you just replace the space with a comma and ignore all other characters?

Comment: ye... i hadn't thought of this ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try with this :

```
([^ \n\t\r]+) ([^ \n\t\r]+)
```

(Don't forget the space after the `^`)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing you are sure of is that the names will be separated by a space and that the first name comes first. As such, I think using the `.` will be fine.

```
([^\s]+) (.+)
```

-or-

```
([\S]+) (.+)
```

(Thanks to @Simon for the second, more readable solution).

This should grab everything before the space and put in a group, and everything after the space(including more spaces) and put that in a group.

---

I just noticed that OP is not switching the order of the groups, if this is the case a simple find a replace on `<space>` will work just fine. But the regex provided will allow you to do `<last name>, <first name>` if desired.

Just as reference, Notepad++ uses PCRE. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: You can also use [\S] instead of [^\s]

Answer (score 1):

If these are all the spaces that are left, search for a single space (or `[ ]+` if you are worried there might be consecutive spaces) and replace with `,`. For the single space option, you don't even need regex mode.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to be working(**reduced the groups from 4 to 2**):

```
    ([A-Z]+[a-z]+) ([A-Z]+[a-z]+)
```

Comment: will fall short on every special charater

Comment: @JamieHutber As I said, it works for the given names. I know there could be better regex but this one similar as OP's regex but works for the given example.

Answer (score -1):

To get the matches use `\n` instead.
Regxp: `([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)`
Replace: `\1,\2`

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of Notepad++. Newer versions support $-syntax.